# padding left smaller than 2 not applied with tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have the following construct to show the logo on the left side and the lettering on the right side of it. However if I try to apply "pl-1" or "pl-1.5" with tailwind the padding will not be applied.

If I use a value which is greater than "pl-1.5" everything works as excepted and the padding is applied correctly.

```
 <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center hover:cursor-pointer">
    <img class="h-8 w-auto"
     src="../assets/logo.svg"
     style="height: 40px; width: 40px"
     alt="foo"/>
    <p class="font-nunito text-2xl pl-1">{{ $t('App.LogoTitle') }}</p>
</div>
```

Why is a padding which is less than "pl-2" not working in this case?

Comment: Do you have a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I'm not able to replicate in the [tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/cpxoIyyexy).

Comment: hey, i tried your code on playtailwindcss, the padding is working perfectly. Maybe you didnt build the css file? check the example here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/ELQSvO6gGs